# Fail to connect to EC2 instance from the root user's shell - Permission denied (publickey) - Windows 10

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am trying to connect to Amazon EC2 instance on windows10. I have already downloaded .pem file. But it showing this error messgae:

```
admin@ec2-*******-*1.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com: Permission denied (publickey).
```

Comment: It would be helpful, if you provide more details like EC2 platform/distribution etc..and, which client are you using to connect to EC2 from Window machine?

Answer (score 0):

"Permission denied (publickey)" and "Authentication failed, permission denied" errors occur if:

1.You're trying to connect using the wrong user name for your AMI.
2.The permissions are incorrect on the instance.
3.The incorrect SSH public key (.pub) file is in the authorized_keys file.
Check the below documentation for resolution,
https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/ec2-linux-fix-permission-denied-errors/

Answer (score 0):

you can use client like 'PuTTY' to connect to EC2 from Windows machine - for this .pem file needs to be converted into .ppk format for authentication. Refer below link for details:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/putty.html

Also,please make sure you are connecting to EC2 using correct user name. Normally, EC2 default user name varies depending on AMI distribution. Few examples below:

```
For Amazon Linux 2 or the Amazon Linux AMI, the user name is ec2-user.
For a CentOS AMI, the user name is centos or ec2-user.
For a Debian AMI, the user name is admin.
For a Fedora AMI, the user name is fedora or ec2-user.
For a RHEL AMI, the user name is ec2-user or root.
For a SUSE AMI, the user name is ec2-user or root.
For an Ubuntu AMI, the user name is ubuntu.
```

Refer to below link for details:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/connection-prereqs.html